# How to solve Page Expired Due to Inactivity in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a PHP developer using Laravel framework and currently i have an application which is in production. The users are being forced to log in every time even if they just logged in in less than 2 mins and get the message **The Page expired due to inactivity**. This is causing me headache as the application is doing just fine in the development environment in my my local machine.

I have search for solutions but non is working for me including generating keys using php artisan command, clear cache,config,route and view, i have also tried to increase the number of minuted for the session to expire to up to 8 hours but the same issue still occurring.

I am actually stranded and don't know what to do else,please i need a help to get out of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which server or PHP version you are using?

Comment: Can you check whether the session cookie is correctly with each request? Also which session driver are you using? Would setting it to e.g. database or file or cookie help at all?

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: 
  Set session lifetime in .env file to `SESSION_LIFETIME=120` (2 hours)
- Option 2:

  Try all of them.

  ```
  composer dump-autoload
  php artisan optimize
  php artisan cache:clear
  php artisan config:clear
  php artisan route:clear
  php artisan view:clear
  ```
- Option 3: if these have no effect add `remember me` checkbox on login form who save session token for long time

Comment: I am using PHP 7.4.2

Comment: I am using file to save session

Comment: i have used the above mentioned artisan commands to no avail except to implement Remember me, will do it and see what happens.Thanks

Comment: I have do as you suggested above @Vildan but the same issue occurs, the user is being logged out at the middle of data entry....what else should i do then